# Nodejs/apidocjs: How do I render the generated documentation at a specific url without a template

Tags: node.js, api-doc

I am writing [apidocs](http://apidocjs.com/) for a nodejs project someone else wrote.
I would like the documentation page to be displayed when someone visits "myurl.com/docs/api". My documentation directory is being placed under "app/public/app/docs/apidoc/" and I am trying to use routes to display it but gives me an error stating:

'Error: Failed to lookup view "/public/app/apidoc/index.html" in views directory "/Path/To/Project/app/views"'

Here is my routes.js entry:

```
app.get('/docs/api', function(req, res) {
   res.render('/app/apidoc/index.html');
});
```

I believe the project uses jade and ejs as they are listed somewhere in the configuration files.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Why are you trying to "render" an HTML file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to render it because its not static. The documentation that gets generated uses a bootstrap template which includes js and css.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how `res.render` works. See the docs: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 5):

You can serve the documentation from the public folder by using this

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And then generate the apidoc with this command

```
apidoc -e "(node_modules|public)" -o public/apidoc
```

Now you can access the documentation by navigating to http://{rooturl}/apidoc